# Android ScrollView won't listen to touch listener if there is nothing to scroll

Tags: android

I have a recyclerview with a list of items and I am trying to implement a two touch drag down gesture to delete an item. The problem is `onTouch` is only being called to lists with a lot of items which activates scrolling. If list is too short, scrolling won't activate, `onTouch` isn't being called.

The following is my code :

```
holder.scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                private float y;
                private boolean hasMoved;
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                            y = event.getY();
                            return true;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                            if (event.getPointerCount() >= 2) {
                                hasMoved = true;
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                            if (hasMoved) {
                                float deltaY = event.getY();
                                if ((deltaY - y) >= 20) {
                                    removeItem(i);
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Is there any work around for this? Like would it be possible to check if scrolling of a scrollview is activated or not?

Comment: set OnTouchListener to the main layout inside scrollview..

Comment: Doesn't work....

Comment: Have you tried to write logs inside onTouch() before switch statement?

Comment: Nothing logged. It doesn't call onTouch() method when child items are few.